# Restful Spring postForObject missing all property values

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, resttemplate

I try to simulate restful server:

```
private void btnPostActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        Issuer issuer = new Issuer();
        issuer.setCountry("Teacher 1");
        issuer.setIssuerName("Department 1");
        String url = txtHost.getText()+txtGet.getText();
        restTemplate.postForObject(url, issuer, Issuer.class) ;
    }
```

Controller code:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/issuer/addIssuer", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public Issuer addIssuer(@ModelAttribute("issuer") Issuer issuer) {

        if (issuer != null) {
            logger.info("Inside addIssuer, adding: " + issuer.toString());
        } else {
            logger.info("Inside addIssuer...");
        }
        issuers.put(issuer.getTicker(), issuer);
        return issuer;

    }
```

I have fill some attributes, but when I debug the server, all values is null.

INFO : com.avaldes.tutorial.RestController - Inside addIssuer, adding: [null, null, null, null]

IssuerName and country is null too..
What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `@ModelAttribute` in your controller. In that case you'll need to send your data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`:

```
MultiValueMap<String, Object> variables = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
variables.add("country", "Teacher 1");
variables.add("issuerName", "Department 1");

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
requestHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(variables, requestHeaders);

String url = txtHost.getText()+txtGet.getText();
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, Issuer.class);
```

Comment: There is just a hint in the documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#rest-form-converter